# Multiple relations between two models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I have a model User and Project in Rails. A Project have a owner (User) and multiple people working on it (User). 
I have tried this model

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User"
  has_many :users

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  has_many :projects
end
```

But then was unable to put values into the record for association. Can someone suggest me what to do.
(I need to get what projects a user own, works on. Project's owner and people who work in it)
Thanks

Comment: This strikes me as a `has_and_belongs_to_many' relationship.

Answer (score 2):

One way of designing the models would be to have a separate `ProjectOwner` and `ProjectUser` models both of them are inherited from `User` model.
and having [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) association between `Project` and `ProjectUser` models.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project_owner
  has_and_belongs_to_many :project_users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  # other common attributes here
end

class ProjectOwner < User
  has_many :projects
end

class ProjectUser < User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
end
```

Add a `project_owner_id` column in your `projects` table.

Create a join table `project_users_projects` which will look like this:

```
create_table :project_users_projects, id: false do |t|
  t.belongs_to :project_user, index: true
  t.belongs_to :project, index: true
end
```

Then, you will be able to do things like these:

```
project_owner = project.project_owner
project_owner_projects = project_owner.projects
project_user_projects = project_user.projects
project_users = project.project_users
```

Comment: how to add data into it, and extract from it. Sorry, I am just starting in ruby

Comment: @HARSHILGOEL look at my updated answer. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: I have to create the join table using rails generate model users_projects, right? and then add to model of users_project belong to user , project

Comment: You don't need a model for that. You just need the `users_projects`. This can be a part of your migration when you create `users` and `project` tables. See the example here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Comment: So, I create table in both or only in user?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88628/discussion-between-harshil-goel-and-k-m-rakibul-islam).

Comment: Would this prevent a single person from being both the owner of the project and working on it?

Comment: When I Run , project.project_users, I get ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'projects_users'

Comment: I cloned your github repo. But, I don't see any such models. Please push the latest changes so that I can take a look what is wrong in there. Thanks.